# How do I create an OIDC login using oclif?

Tags: node.js, openid-connect, oclif

Can anyone please supply an example of using OCLIF to do an OIDC login from the command line.  I think that the idea is that the login command should open a browser to login the page and spawn a server to capture authorization response.  I am struggling with the implementation though.

Answer (score 0):

@Ken, did you eventually find the solution? I have the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

For the time of the question, I don't know if you still need it but I ended up bumping into it and I implemented something in this repository that might help:

https://github.com/wnqueiroz/oclif-keycloak-oauth2-flows-sample

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33628104)